# search and replace files in linux(sed)

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to search and replace the following:

```
<?php 
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

with

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

so far I have tried this:

```
find . \( -name "*.php" \) -exec grep -Hn "<?php <\!DOCTYPE HTML>" {} \; -exec sed -i 's/<?php <\!DOCTYPE HTML>/<\!DOCTYPE HTML>/g' {} \;
```

But it's not finding any instances of files with my needle string which exists on  my server.

Comment: what could I have used am new to this.

Comment: Don't just say “it [is] not working”: say *how* it isn't working. You've told us what you want to happen: also tell us what happens instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec grep -lZz '^<?php[[:space:]]\+<!DOCTYPE HTML>' {} + |
xargs -r0 sed -i '^<?php[[:space:]]*$/,1d'
```

**Edit:** The previous version didn't work due to the character `\n` in the pattern. The updated version avoid this character.

Comment: It's working here. I assume the regex doesn't match because your files look a bit different. Maybe there are space characters or CR at the end of the first line. Does it work if you replace `\n` with `[ \t\r]*\n`?

Comment: Yay for learning new stuff, in this case getting grep to successfully match something that spans several lines by using `-z` (c:
I also like the grep -Z/xargs -0 combo to make things safer.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk (for `RS='\0'` to read the whole file as one record) and assuming your file names don't contain newlines all you need is the clear, simple:

```
find . -name '*.php' -print |
while IFS= read -r file; do
    gawk -v RS='\0' '{gsub(/<\?php\n<!DOCTYPE HTML>/,"<!DOCTYPE HTML>"); print}' "$file" > tmp &&
    mv tmp "$file"
done
```